# strange output during git merge

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge

I am in a clone named /private/gmills, and I ran `git merge main_int`.

I am seeing a reference to another clone for some other user on a different machine. What does this mean?

I have only 1 remote configured and it isn't pointing to this other clone or machine.

**Warning message :**

```
warning: Failed to merge submodule projects/kernel (multiple merges found)
 1b64e534e162316a124f98edef6584d7ead1c563: > Merge branch 'main_int' into main_int_infra_xlp
 fe1ffcf1f49d8741e03710837fc6e1179b1cf222: > merge from main_int workspace:/private/sriniv/projects/kernel on build02
```

**Information on remote repositories :**

```
git remote -v
origin  git@server:flt/root.git (fetch)
origin  git@server:flt/root.git (push)
```

Comment: The warning deals with a submodule. Could you give us more information on that submodule? What is its remote repository? I believe the problem lies in the fact your merge also concerns this `projects/kernel` submodule.

Comment: Post `.git/config` and `.gitmodules` files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the git branches you're merging have submodule issues. Look at the `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` files within your repositories to find out which submodule is being referenced.